# Is there an official English pronunciation of Planetes?

Tags: planetes

The Japanese title is プラネテス ΠΛΑΝΗΤΕΣ. The second word, ΠΛΑΝΗΤΕΣ, is Greek for "planets" or "wandering stars". The first word is a transcription of the Greek word into Japanese using Katakana. In Romaji it would be "Puranetesu".

The English title is ΠΛΑΝΗΤΕΣ Planetes. How should this be pronounced in English? I've used all the following, but I'm really hoping someone here knows or can find the official pronunciation.

- Plane-tess
- Planets
- Planet E-S

Comment: Assuming you follow the Japanese pronunciation, it would be "plah-neh-tess" (IPA: /plænətes/, probably). The other three you suggest would be written differently in Japanese - "pleyn-tess" would be プラインテス _puraintesu_; "plah-nets" would be プラネッツ _puranettsu_; "plah-net-ee-ess" would be プラネットイーエス _puranettoiiesu_ or something. I imagine the localizers have to have pronounced it in English at some point in an interview or similar; someone who can track something like that down would probably be able to give a better answer.

Comment: Yeah, it would be great if someone on here owned the DVD set. I think it has some English commentaries / interviews. Maybe they actually say the title's name at some point. It's out of print and decently expensive to get now.... You all are probably right that the pronunciation is like "plah-neh-tess" or "pla-ne-tes", in English. I would just like some kind of official source for that.

Answer (score 4):

The name "planet" comes from the Ancient Greek term πλανήτης (planḗtēs), meaning "wanderer." In modern Greek, it's more or less pronounced "planítis. "

Note that the Japanese romanization is "Puranetesu," プラネテス. Planets is romanized "Puranettosu, " プラネットス.

By inference, we can assume that the title is pronounced "PLA-NE-TES. "